# Как перейти в процесс?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

У меня есть VPS-сервер под ubuntu 17, я подключаюсь к нему через putty, запускаю скрипт, который запускает сервер, я обрываю сессию ssh, захожу заново по ssh, процесс запущенного сервера висит, но вопрос в том: как мне перейти в этом процесс т.е при запуске этого сервера в терминале писалась информация, при новой сессии мне надо получить эту информацию? Как это сделать?

Comment: перед тем как запускать скрипт запустите screen. для повторного входа используйте screen -R (если не изменяет паямять). В общем почитайте про программу screen, она специально для этого

Comment: В общем случае при обрыве ssh процесс должен помереть, если не сразу - так через несколько минут. Так что и подключаться к нему смысла мало

Comment: Если вам нужно запустить процесс навсегда, не мелочитесь и пишите systemd-юнит (вышеупомянутый screen тоже можно, но это несерьёзно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем случае, Ваш процесс должен "умереть", когда отключается терминал. Но видимо Ваш "сервер" умеет правильно "демонизироваться". Если это обычный веб сервер apache/nginx, тогда можно посмотреть логи в их соответствующих папках - у nginx это /var/log/nginx. Если же сервер "кастомный" - тогда нужно искать уже у него.

Но возможно, все не  так плохо. Обычно такие "сервисы" всегда можно запустить в screen/tmux и тогда все будет очень "приятно". То есть, запускаем screen/tmux (screen очень часто уже бывает установлен) и попадаем как будто в ту же консоль. В этой консоли уже запускаем нужную программу. Теперь, если соединение разорвется, то можно всегда переподключится к серверу и подключится к такой "виртуальной консольке". В случае tmux - это `tmux attach`. screen - в начале делаем `screen -ls`, смотрим запущенные сессии, а потом `screen -r <session>` - подключаемся. За деталями - в документацию.